# I get a segmentation fault when implementing a append function for a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am defining head as a global variable. The user enters integers which should be appended to a singly linked list. I implemented the append function, but it gives me a segmentation fault.

```
void Append(int x)
{
    struct Node *temp, *current;
    temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp -> data = x;


    temp -> next = NULL;

    if(head->next ==NULL)
    {
            head = temp;

    }
    else{

            //current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            current = head;
            while(1)//current != NULL)
            {
                    if(current->next ==NULL)
                    {
                            current =current -> next;
                            printf("added to the end\n");
                            break;
                    }

                    current = current -> next;
            }
    }
}
```

The main function is given below:

```
int main()
{
    //create empty List
    head =NULL;

    printf("How many numbers?\n");
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i =0; i<n; i++)
    {

            printf("Enter the number\n");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            //Insert(x);
            Append(x);
            Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and change to `if(current->next ==NULL){current -> next = temp,;`

Answer (score 1):

you set head to null

```
head =NULL;
```

and the next time you access it, you're trying to access one of it's properties

```
if(head->next ==NULL)
```

You can't do this, because there is no `head->next` because `head` is null

Answer (score 0):

Since you initialize `head` to `NULL`, this line causes an error:

```
if(head->next ==NULL)
```

As you are attempting to access member `next` of a `NULL` pointer.

To fix this, allocate `head` before calling `Append`, or check for `head` being `NULL` inside `Append`.

Answer (score 0):

//Insert(x);=> Enable this and update valid head node. If not in Append() function, if(head->next) should be changed to if(head). That is head pointer must be validated before accessing next..